# Nested fragment with viewpager where viewpager not loading the fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

I have a activity in which i am loading a fragment

```
Home fragmentA = new Home();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransactionA = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransactionA.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragmentA);
        fragmentTransactionA.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

in my home fragment i have a slidingtablayout and viewpager

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="mobile.data.woises.fragment.Home">

    <mobile.data.woises.tabs.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/main_color"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#0bbea5"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

and my java code of my home fragment is this

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

    View infHome;
    SlidingTabLayout slidingTabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    private FragmentPageAdapterHome Pa;
    CharSequence Titles[] = {"Requirements", "Notification"};
    int Numboftabs = 2;

    public Home() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        infHome = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home2, container, false);

        return infHome;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) infHome.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        viewPager = (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager) infHome.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        // adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getResources(), getChildFragmentManager());
        //  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        Pa = new FragmentPageAdapterHome(getChildFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        viewPager.setAdapter(Pa);
        slidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(Color.parseColor("#0bbea5"));
        slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }

}
```

And my FragmentPageAdapterHome is this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import mobile.data.woises.fragment.Notification;
import mobile.data.woises.fragment.Requirements;

/*import com.example.uday.innohabit.fragments.FragA;
import com.example.uday.innohabit.fragments.FragB;
import com.example.uday.innohabit.fragments.FragC;*/


/**
 * Created by Uday on 05-11-2015.
 */
public class FragmentPageAdapterHome extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    private Map<Integer, String> mFragmentTags;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private Context mContext;
    private String WoisesId;
    CharSequence Titles[];
    int NumofTabs;
    //int icons[] = {R.drawable.search,R.drawable.cart,R.drawable.quickorder};

    //String tabTitle;
    public FragmentPageAdapterHome(FragmentManager fm, CharSequence mTitles[],
                                   int mNumbOfTabsumb, Context context) {
        super(fm);


        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumofTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;


        mFragmentManager = fm;
        mFragmentTags = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        mContext = context;

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
Log.d("FragmentPageAdapterHome","Arg="+arg0);
        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                Requirements requirements = new Requirements();
                return requirements;
            case 1:
                Notification notification = new Notification();
                return notification;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return NumofTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Object obj = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        if (obj instanceof Fragment) {
            // record the fragment tag here.
            Fragment f = (Fragment) obj;
            String tag = f.getTag();
            mFragmentTags.put(position, tag);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
        String tag = mFragmentTags.get(position);
        if (tag == null)
            return null;
        return mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }
}
```

all the Log in the Requirement and the notification fragment  is being displayed in Logcat that means the function is being called but the fragment is not being displayed please help me where i am making the mistake .
I was using the getsupportfragmentmanager() but someone on stack overflow posted that i should use the  getChildFragmentManager() when it is nested fragment .
what should i do .please help me i am unable to figure out what is problem.

Comment: Why are you using weight in `FrameLayout` in your Home Fragment xml?

Answer (score 1):

You set your `ViewPagers` `height` to `0px`. `layout_weight` is a feature from `LinearLayout`, since you are using `FrameLayout`, nothing is shown. Possible fixes:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="mobile.data.woises.fragment.Home">

    <mobile.data.woises.tabs.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/main_color"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#0bbea5"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>

//or:
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="mobile.data.woises.fragment.Home">

    <mobile.data.woises.tabs.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/main_color"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#0bbea5"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Also, don't use `px`, since your layouts will look different on different screens. Use `dp` (density points) instead!

Comment: that was exactly my problem